# How to limit (Flutter) string min/max length with security rules in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firestore Database and I'm now trying to add security rules after building many of the pages without security rules.  That was definitely a huge mistake.  I have reviewed a lot of the documentation and watched a bunch of the Firebase security rules videos which are all clear but as a beginner I still need guidance.  I have also reviewed SO threads which have helped get me to this point.

My goal is to have client side validation and server side validation that requires a minimum of 3 characters and allows a maximum of 20 characters when a user creates a new account and adds their userName.  And the same rules should apply when they update their userName.  Here is an image of the database.

[image]

My security rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
    allow read, write, update: if request.auth != null
    && request.auth.uid == userId
    && resource.data.username.length >= 3
    && resource.data.username.length <= 30
    && resource.data.undername is string;
    }
```

In the Rules Playground I get an error message:

Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [10], column [28]. Null value error.

And in the console I get a similar error message:

Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with my rules code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be checking [`request.resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) which contains incoming data and not [`resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) which holds existing data from the document. Also try using [`size()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#size) instead of `.length` to check string length:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write, update: if request.auth != null
        && request.auth.uid == userId
        && request.resource.data.username.size() >= 3
        && request.resource.data.username.size() <= 30
        && request.resource.data.undername is string;
    }
  }
}
```

For example, if current value of username is 'Jim' in the document and you are trying to update it to 'James', value of `resource.data.username.size()` would be `3` (length of existing name) and `request.resource.data.username.size()` would be `5` (length of new name). It's length of the new name that you are supposed to measure so you need to use `request.resource`.

Comment: Rules playground doesn't like: request.resource.auth.uid == userId but other than that your suggestion seems to have resolved all of the other issues.  The new error says: Property resource is undefined on object.  If I need to ask a new question on SO I will do so.  Thank you very much for the help.  I can see I need to read the documentation more to understand the errors you pointed out.  And I have seen your answers all over SO so I am not questioning your expertise.  I am very appreciative.

Comment: @CarletonY in case of auth uid it's `request.auth.uid` only (no resource as in my answer above) but in others you need `.data`.. it's `request.resource.data`. `request.auth` contains auth info of requesting user and `request.resource.data` contains the data user is trying to update/add.

Comment: You clearly said that in your first answer but when I tried it, I got the error: Error: simulator.rules line [7], column [28]. Null value error so that is why I thought maybe using request.resource.auth.uid would work.  It didn't work either so I will review documentation further and try to figure out this new null value error.  It's really puzzling.

Comment: @CarletonY auth info (`request.auth`) and data being updated (`request.resource.data`) are 2 different things here. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) has better explanation for that. Coming to `resource.data`, this will contain existing data at the path being updated. To fix the another issue you have right now, can you use `request.auth.uid` instead of `request.resource.data.uid`? The user UID is part of auth object and not data payload.